# My level of significance is 1 for all my variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Basically, I'm trying to run a logistic regression, to predict, if the state and year is given will the birth level in the particular state would be high (1 = high, 0 = otherwise).

How the Data looks like. (2015 - 2018)

[image]

```
train = gData_dummy$Year<2018  # equal to the year less than 2005 (year 2001 to 2004)
glm.fit <- glm(Level_d ~ Year + State,
               data = gData_dummy,
               family = binomial("logit"), maxit = 100,
               subset = train)
summary(glm.fit)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: It looks like `glm()` didn't converge.  Why did you limit it using `maxit = 100`?

Comment: Actually am not sure as well, I saw someone else's code that fixed their the model that did not converge by using maxit, so I tot I'd try @user2554330

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a question for cross-validated, but...

The regression here failed to fit, most likely because you have columns which are linear combinations of others (i.e. they are redundant). What you can do is to fit a regularized model such as the ones from the package `glmnet`.